# Controller Spec #Show Action: exoected: [Object], got: nil Error - RSpec 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, tdd

I am going through Aaron Sumner's Everyday Rails Testing with RSpec (3) book, and can't get passed the following step:

I am trying to spec out a `users#show` action with:

**users_controller_spec:**

```
...    
describe 'GET #show' do

  it "assigns the requested contact to @user" do
    user = create(:user)
    get :show, id: user.id
    expect(assigns(:user)).to eq user
  end


  it "renders the :show template" do
    user = create(:user)
    get :show, id: user.id
    expect(response).to render_template :show
  end

end
...
```

**users_controller:**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show]

  ### Read:
  def show
    ...
  end


  private

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

**application_controller helpers:**

```
  def authenticate
    redirect_to home_path, alert: 'Please log in first' if current_user.nil?
  end

  private 

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  helper_method :current_user
```

**Errors:**

```
Failures:

  1) UsersController GET #show assigns the requested user to @user
     Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:user)).to eq user

       expected: #<User id: 1, ...">
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) UsersController GET #show renders the :show template
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template :show
       expecting <"show"> but rendering with <[]>
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: _\should this be changed to user.id?_ -- I think yes.

Comment: 1) `expected [object] got nil`   2) `expect(response).to render_template :show but rendering with <[]>`. Same two errors I listed in the OP

Comment: may be your #show action is empty.. that's why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue comes from `before_action :authenticate` either you need to set yourself as authenticated in the specs or you need to skip authentication for the `show` action.

You would normally test like:

```
context 'when logged in' do
  before(:each) do
    set_as_logged_in
  end

  # your specs
end
```

where the `set_as_logged_in` method would differ based on the way you are authenticating. Then you could also have a `'when not logged in'` context to verify the action behaves as expected when you are not logged in.

Comment: yep! I was also using a local var instead of an instance var (`user` vs `@user`). Thanks!